# How to update table field = field+1 in laravel eloquent update query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I want to update a query in laravel where `$field = $field+1` . It works fine using `mysqli_query`. But It is not working laravel orm.

I want to run this query in laravel orm

```
$sql = "Update $tbl set cnt=cnt+1 where user_id='x'"
```

When running this query in mysql I get following results

```
If cnt =1 in databases it will increment $cnt = $cnt+1 = 1+1 =2
```

I want to run this sql query in laravel orm

```
$where = ['user_id' => 'x'];
$field = ['cnt' => 'cnt+1'];
$tbl = 'log_cnt';
Capsule::table($tbl)->where($where)->update($field);
```

But After running this query output will show `$cnt=0` in database

Comment: Have you tried below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incrementing or decrementing a value of a column

**To increment single column**

```
Capsule::table('log_cnt')->increment('cnt');
     Query: UPDATE log_cnt SET cnt = cnt + 1;

Capsule::table('log_cnt')->increment('cnt', 5);
     Query: UPDATE log_cnt SET cnt = cnt + 5;
```

**To decrement single column**

```
Capsule::table('log_cnt')->decrement('cnt');
     Query: UPDATE log_cnt SET cnt = cnt - 1;

Capsule::table('log_cnt')->decrement('cnt', 5);
     Query: UPDATE log_cnt SET cnt = cnt - 5;
```

**You may also specify additional columns to update:**

```
Capsule::table('log_cnt')->increment('cnt', 1, ['user_id' => 'x']);
    Query: UPDATE log_cnt SET cnt = cnt + 1, user_id = 'x';
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#increment-and-decrement